# What is a de-reflection optimization in HotSpot JIT and how does it implemented?

Tags: java, optimization, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot

Watching [Towards a Universal VM](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Towards-a-Universal-VM) presentation, I studied this slide, which lists all the optimisations that HotSpot JIT does:[image]

In the `language-specific techniques` section there is a de-reflection. I tried to find some information about it accross the Internet, but failed. I understood that this optimization eliminates reflection costs in some way, but I'm interested in details. Can someone clarify this, or give some useful links?

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with [`MethodHandles.Lookup#unreflect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#unreflect-java.lang.reflect.Method-)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is an optimization to reduce Reflection costs, though it is implemented mostly in Class Library rather than in JVM.

Before Java 1.4 `Method.invoke` worked through a JNI call to VM runtime. Each invocation required at least two transitions from Java to Native and back to Java. The VM runtime parsed a method signature, verified that types of passed arguments were correct, performed boxing/unboxing and constructed a new Java frame for a called method. All that was rather slow.

Since Java 1.4 `Method.invoke` uses dynamic bytecode generation if a method is called more than 15 times (configurable via `sun.reflect.inflationThreshold` system property). A special Java class responsible for calling the given particular method is built in run-time. This class implements [sun.reflect.MethodAccessor](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/70e3553d9d6e/src/share/classes/sun/reflect/MethodAccessor.java) which `java.lang.reflect.Method` delegates calls to.

The approach with dynamic bytecode generation is much faster since it

- does not suffer from JNI overhead;
- does not need to parse method signature each time, because each method invoked via Reflection has its own unique MethodAccessor;
- can be further optimized, e.g. these MethodAccessors can benefit from all regular JIT optimizations like inlining, constant propagation, autoboxing elimination etc.

Note, that this optimization is implemented mostly in [Java code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/70e3553d9d6e/src/share/classes/sun/reflect/MethodAccessorGenerator.java) without JVM assistance. The only thing HotSpot VM does to make this optimization possible - is skipping bytecode verification for such generated MethodAccessors. Otherwise the verifier would not allow, for example, to call private methods.